# JQuery - getting values from selected table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with multiple elements. The first element is a check box which will trigger an event in Javascript. what I need to do is:
1. check to see if the check box value is true
2. if true, get the values from the table elements
   a. some column values are text
   b. some columns contain text boxes (

```
    <table class="rowClick" id="page" width="100%">                 
<thead>
    <tr id="p_1">                         
        <th colspan=9 align=center >Select/Change and Update Selections</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="p_2">
        <th>Select</th>
        <th class="table-sortable:default">Class</th>                    
        <th class="table-sortable:default">Desc</th>
        <th class="table-sortable:default">Weight</th>                         
        <th class="table-sortable:currency">Pott Dia</th>                         
        <th class="table-sortable:currency">Pott Ht</th>                         
        <th class="table-sortable:currency">Pott Stack Ht</th>                         
        <th class="table-sortable:currency">Tower Width</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>                 
        <tbody>
        <tr id="p_3">                             
        <td align=center>
        <input class = "prodSel" type="checkbox" id="chk[]"></td>                             
        <td align=center>00100</td>                             
        <td align=center>C100</td>                             
        <td align=center>XL</td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=4.75></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=4.68></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=0.33></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=40.40></td>                             
        </tr>
        <tr id="p_4">                             
        <td align=center><input class = "prodSel" type="checkbox" id="chk[]"></td>                             
        <td align=center>00140</td>                             
        <td align=center>C200S</td>                             
        <td align=center>CL</td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=6.00></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=5.43></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=0.43></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=42.00></td>                             
        </tr>
        <tr id="p_5">                             
        <td align=center><input class = "prodSel" type="checkbox" id="chk[]"></td>                             
        <td align=center>00140</td>                             
        <td align=center>C200S</td>                             
        <td align=center>CU</td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=6.00></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=5.43></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=0.43></td>                             
        <td align=center><input size=5 type="text" value=42.00></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
    rowSelect: function(event) {
      var work = [];
      //        var rowIndex =   $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
      var chkbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').child(0);
      if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked){
        for(var i=0;i<17;i++){
            if(i<3){
                var s = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(i)').text();
            }
            else{
                var s = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(i)').val();
            }
            work[i]=s;
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is at the very beginning where I am trying to get the value of the checkbox (checked or not). I thought I could either grab the object and then check the val(), or just get the val() from teh child, but nothing is working yet. What I need is a way to get the value for the checkbox and also get the value from the text input boxes.

I have a fiddle here with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/tCh3P/19/

**----> SOLUTION <----**

Ok, here was my final solution using the functionality provided below and some other neat attributes for anyone that cares to have a look. I changed it to populate a JSON rather than using arrays, but the overall functionality is valid.

```
  var proddta =
  {
   init: function(){
    // hook into the get delete/update buttons
    var del = $("#delete");
    for (var i = 0, ii = del.length; i < ii; i++){
        $(del).bind("click", proddta.deleteListener2);
    }
    var upd = $("#update");
    for (var i = 0, ii = upd.length; i < ii; i++){
        $(upd).bind("click", proddta.updateListener);
    }
},

updateListener: function(event){
    myJSON = new Object();
    $('.prodSel:checked').each(function() {
        proddta.getArrays(this, myJSON);
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
        alert('dastring: '+dataString);
        /*
            var url = 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/truck/webServices/products.svc.php?update=1';
            $.post(url, {data: dataString}, function(res){
                proddta.showResult(res);
        });
        */
    });

},

deleteListener2: function(event){
    myJSON = new Object();
    $('.prodSel:checked').each(function(){
        proddta.getArrays(this, myJSON);
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
        /*
           var url = 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/truck/webServices/products.svc.php?update=0';
        $.post(url, {data: dataString}, function(res){
            var obj = $.evalJSON(res);
            if(obj.somebool === true)
            $("#result").html(obj.hello + ' ' + obj.array[1] + obj.worked + ". Message from PHP: "+obj.php_message);
        });
        */
        alert('dastring: '+dataString);
    });
},

getArrays: function(evt, myjson){
    var val = proddta.getColumnCount(this);
    $closestTr = $(evt).closest('tr');
    var chkbox = $closestTr.find('td:eq(0)').find(':checkbox');
    if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.is(':checked')) {
        var s = '';
        var id = '';
        for (var i = 1; i < val; i++) {
            if (i >= 1 && i < 4) {
                s = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').text();
                id = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id');
            } else {
                s = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').find(':input').val();
                id = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').find(':input').attr('id');
            }
            myjson[id] = s;
        }
    }
    else {
    // handle this exception...
    }
},

getColumnCount: function(evt){
    var colCount = 0;
    $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
            colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
    });
    alert(colCount);
    return colCount;
 },
 }
 proddta.init();
```

Comment: Please show your HTML. I suspect there are easier selectors to find the various elements than you're using.

Comment: (see fiddle) Thanks for the insight... suggestions?

Comment: I dont see you are adding value="" attribute to checkboxes e.g `<input class = "prodSel" type="checkbox" id="chk[]">`

Comment: Please update your post to ask a single question per SO's guidelines.

Comment: Similarly, if you've implemented your own solution (and that's both 'allowed' and awesome), don't pat the answer in the question itself, add it add as an answer, and accept that answer. That way the question becomes officially, and conclusively, answered. Plus, people can then upvote your answer, and give you rep. =)

Answer (score 2):

To find the checkbox:

```
var checkbox = $(this).closest().find('input:checkbox:first');
if (checkbox.is(':checked')){
    // checkbox is checked
}
```

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
- [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Comment: `$(this)` in his code is TD and can be any column. Need not be the column with checkbox

Comment: This is a suggestion/recommendations but not an answer.

Comment: Thank you all I will try all of these suggestions and mark the solution. As always, you are the BEST resource on the net

Comment: @Vega: I edited the code at around the same time as you left the comment, adding the `.closest()` call. As to it not being an answer, the question appears to be: 'how do I find if the checkbox is checked?' I realise he asks for the value, but there's no value attribute for the checkboxes, and he appears, in the code, to be looking for "if it's checked," not "what value is it."

Answer (score 2):

Your code required a bunch of fixes and finally it worked. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tCh3P/5/)

```
rowSelect: function(event) {
    alert('hello 1');
    var work = [];
    var $closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var chkbox = $closestTr.find('td:eq(0)').find(':checkbox');

    alert('hello 2 ' + chkbox.is(':checked'));
    if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.is(':checked')) {
        alert('hello 3');
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            if (i != 0 && i < 4) {
                s = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').text();
            } else {
                s = $closestTr.find('td:eq(' + i + ')').find(':input').val();
            }
            work.push(s);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('hello 99');
    }
    alert('hello 4 ' + work.join(' '));
}
```

Comment: I am sure. Thanks so much. i am buildng a basic class structure to manage these from this point forward so i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `chkbox` variable declaration to this:

```
var chkbox = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').get(0);
```